# Nested pattern matching with preg_match_all (Regex and PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm working with text data that contains special flags in the form of "{X}" or "{XX}" where X could be any alphanumeric character. Special meaning is assigned to these flags when they are adjacent or when they are separated. I need a regex which will match adjacent flags AND separate each flag in the group.

For Example, given the following input:

```
{B}{R}: Target player loses 1 life.
{W}{G}{U}: Target player gains 5 life.
```

The output should be approximate:

```
("{B}{R}",
 "{W}{G}{U}")

("{B}",
 "{R}")

("{W}",
 "{G}",
 "{U}")
```

My PHP code is returning the adjacents array properly, but the split array contains only the last matching flag in each group:

```
$input = '{B}{R}: Target player loses 1 life.
{W}{G}{U}: Target player gains 5 life.';
$pattern = '#((\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}})+)#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $results);
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {B}{R}
            [1] => {W}{G}{U}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {B}{R}
            [1] => {W}{G}{U}
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => {R}
            [1] => {U}
        )

)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no actual nesting here, but just repetetion. Unless I misunderstood, you just want to break out each token. Then remove the `+` and outer parens, and let `preg_match_all` return each alone. // Of course if you want to find occurences in your input flow text, then use your original approach and reprocess it again in a second run. Breaking them out with one PCRE call isn't feasible, short of specifying a limited set of optional token occurences `(\{\w})?(\{\w})?(\{\w})?`.

Comment: Well I want to break out each group "{B}{R}" and "{W}{G}{U}". I also want to break out every flag individually "{B}", "{R}", "{W}", "{G}", and "{U}" in a separate array. I guess the only way is to run two regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($results[1]);
foreach($results[0] AS $match){
    preg_match_all('/\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}}/', $match, $r);
    $results[] = $r[0];
}
```

That's the only way I know of to create your Required datastructure.  Though, a preg_split would work as well:

```
unset($results[1]);
foreach($results[0] AS $match)
    $results[] = preg_split('/(?<=})(?=\{)/', $match);
```